# How to implement a listener to check i have read a text file and ignore it

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written a small program to monitor a folder. I have not used the folderWatcher in .NET because multiple files can be added to the folder simultaneously and folderWatcher can sometimes miss them. Basically, I am checking the folder for a file that starts and ends with certain characters. The timer is checking the folder every 10 seconds.

My issue: my program will read the same file multiple times. I need to set a condition or have a listener check if the file has already been read to ignore it.

The problem is I'm not sure how to go about this, can anyone shed some light on the best way to maybe implement a listener that will check if I have read this file and ignore it and move onto the next file, please?

I couldn't find another thread on here that helped me with the answer I am looking for.

Comment: As far as I understand, you program does not stop in between of two runs. So you could store the processed files in a list. Which could be persisted in case your server restarts.

Comment: I don't have any issues with server restarts, I just don't want to read the same text file more than once. So I need a way to check if I have already read that file and ignore it. I am not sure how to go about doing just that.

Comment: Ever hear of a _flag_?

Comment: yep, a bool right? true / false condition.

Comment: What about moving read files in another folder?

Comment: Oxlade, if your goal is to detect file changes (edit,create,delete but not including reads) the `FileSystemWatcher` class should do the trick. I just tested the example code in the [msdn doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) and it was able to detect multiple file changes as is your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Coskun
That is a good option and it does work.
For simplicity i went a different route, I  add the file names to a list then check the list pre-execution, if the list does not contain that file name it executes. I go on to count the file names in the list and output the total on each pass to a text field that tell me how many files i ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, you sould keep somewhere (maybe in a text file) the last scan date and can check the creation time of files.

```
    void ReadFiles()
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime lastScanDate = GetLastScanDate();

            SetLastScanDate();
            foreach (string filePath in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\cozogul\Desktop\test"))
            {
                System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);
                if (fi.CreationTime >= lastScanDate)
                {
                    //read file
                }
                else
                {
                    //Don't read file.
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log your error
        }
    }

    DateTime GetLastScanDate()
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Users\cozogul\Desktop\test\datefile.txt"))
        {
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\Users\cozogul\Desktop\test\datefile.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                string dateString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString);
                return date;
            }
        }
        //Will read all files.
        else
            return DateTime.MinValue;
    }

    public void SetLastScanDate()
    {
        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\Users\cozogul\Desktop\test\datefile.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Create))
        {
            byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
```

Or you can keep filenames in a file or a database table to check a file is before read.

Comment: Thanks, Coskun, I will have a try at doing that.

Comment: I modified my code, you can take the exemple if you wish.

Comment: I checked the last version of my code, works correctly.